# How to write out results of a program to Excel?

Tags: java, excel, webdriver, apache-poi, xls

I'm trying to capture all of the links from a website, print them out, and then store them in an Excel file. My program is correctly displaying the results but isn't storing them in an Excel file.

```
package Frameworks;

public class ArrayConversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/09/test.html");
        List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        Iterator<WebElement> itr = li.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String link = itr.next().getText();
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            stringList.add(link);

            String array[] = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
            for (String str : array) {
                System.out.println(str);
                xlWrite(array);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void xlWrite(String[] array) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Inside XL Write");
        File fil = new File("C:\\Users\\Kshitij\\Desktop\\linkstest.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sht = wb.createSheet("Results");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            HSSFRow row = sht.createRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(array[i]);
            }
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fil);
            wb.write(fout);
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
            wb.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to write out the Excel file? What part doesn't work?

Comment: I'm able to execute your program with sample data. Could you be more specific on which part of your program is failing. On another note, you should call xlWrite method out of for loop.

Comment: From main method, every link is displayed in console. Problem arises when control goes to xlWrite and it is not able to fetch data from main method. Hence blank excel file is written.